# Vim: Ignoring errors in a list of mapped substitutions

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I have a number of regex substitutions I regularly do, and therefore want to map a key to do this easily. However, if one of the regexes to be substituted aren't found in the file, my key mapping stops due to `E486: Pattern not found` and no further replacements are carried out. E.g. if the mapping in my vimrc is

```
map <F12> :%s/spam/foo/<enter>:%s/ham/bar/<enter>:%s/eggs/baz/<enter>
```

and there is no `ham` in my file, `eggs` won't get substituted. Is there a flag I can put on the substitutions to ignore errors? I've read `:help regex` and `:help map` without finding anything usable.

Alternately, is there another, easier, more obvious way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: (You can save the last `/` if you don't append flags like `g` or the `e` Birei proposed: `:%s/spam/foo<CR>` Same goes even for the second delimiter if you just want to delete something (only the first occurrence per line): `:%s/spam<cr>`)

Comment: I know. I just don't like having unclosed slashes ;)

Comment: Slashes don't go by pairs :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the `/e` flag to each substitution command. It doesn't show error messages and continues as if no error had ocurred. This would be the new mapping:

```
map <F12> :%s/spam/foo/e<enter>:%s/ham/bar/e<enter>:%s/eggs/baz/e<enter>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, does what it says on the tin. Don't know how I missed that >.<

Answer (score 11):

You can add a "flag" at the end of pattern:

```
:%s/spam/foo/e
```

won't spit an error if it doesn't find `spam` and allow you to continue.

See `:help flags`.